# WPBakery Page Builder Backend Editor Not Working

Tags: wordpress, wpbakery

I have recently set up a new website with WPBakery page builder however the backend editor is not displaying. I only get the options to edit content under the "Visual" or "Text" tabs and there is no option for a block editor (please see screenshot linked @ bottom). I have installed the "Classic Editor" plugin which has resolved this for me on other websites however it does not appear to make a difference.

Has anyone else had this issue / found a solution? I am running WPBakery page builder plugin v.6.1 and Wordpress v.5.5.1.

Cheers,

M.

[Page Builder Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mTlsM.jpg)

Comment: Are you sure the plugin is Active? it doesn't seem to be.

Answer (score 5):

Plugin Not Working After wordpress 5.5 Update
WPbakery / Visual Composer

**ISSUE RESOLVED**

Just Install

https://wordpress.org/plugins/enable-jquery-migrate-helper/

It works 100% fine

**ANOTHER SOLUTION**

The ultimate solution [fix] for WPBakery Page Builder under WP 5.5
Now, if nothing of the above have worked for you. The only thing left to consider is to actually downgrade your WordPress 5.5 back to say the last stable version which currently in 5.4.2.

There are basically two methods to downgrade the WordPress. You can download the WordPress 5.4.2 distribution package and install over the current, by uploading and extracting the archive on your hosting. But that’s the worst case scenario. So, here is the most simple and hassle-free option:

Download and activate the plugin WP Downgrade.
Go to the plugin settings (Settings -> WP Downgrade) and input the version 5.4.2 and click Save changes.
The page will refresh and suggest you to go to the Dashboard -> Updates. There you need to click on Re-install to version 5.4.2
Done!

Comment: I can verify wordpress Version 5.3.2 works. Additionally, according to a user on this thread https://wordpress.org/support/topic/wpbakery-backend-editor-is-not-working/page/2/
disabling gutenburg editor in WP Bakery settings also solves the problem.

Comment: Installing `jQuery migrate helper` plugin fixed the issue for me. Works fine for wordpress 5.8.2 with wpbakery builder version 6.2

Answer (score 4):

Facing the Same issue. WordPress 5.7.2.
I just **deactivate** the **Essential Grid plugin** and It's working fine.
I hope it works for you too.

Answer (score 1):

I am on 5.7.2 version, and WPBakery is acting weird, so I disabled my plugins and activated one at a time. I found out that the Essential Grid Plugin is the culprit, I disabled it, and the issue gone. I hope they will fix this soon.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to WK Bakery Page Builder > Role Manager > Post Types and see if it is enabled for the post type you are trying to edit.